# How can I draw a diagonal line in the top left cell of a table using Markdown?

Tags: markdown

I want to make a table that has a diagonal line in the top left cell like this (the image is from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399639/how-to-create-a-multirow-latex-table-with-line-on-main-diagonal)).

[image: screenshot of the desired result]

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: This is not possible with markdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an ASCII table and use [diagonal line characters](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+27CD) to achieve this.

```
-------------------------
|⟍  to|     |     |     |
|  ⟍  |item1|item2|item3|
|from⟍|     |     |     |
-------------------------
|     |⟍    |long |     |
|item1|  ⟍  |text |     |
|     |    ⟍|     |     |
-------------------------
|     |     |⟍    |     |
|item2|     |  ⟍  |     |
|     |     |    ⟍|     |
-------------------------
|     |     |     |⟍    |
|item3|     |     |  ⟍  |
|     |     |     |    ⟍|
-------------------------
```